# Hidden set in the view but null in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-first

I try to get a value in my controller, it's set in the view (in a hidden field) but once in the post method the field is null. 
My model :

```
 public partial class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }


    public int? CustomerAddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerAddressId")]
    public virtual CustomerAddress CustomerAddress { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerAddressBillingId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerAddressBillingId")]
    public virtual CustomerAddressBilling CustomerAddressBilling { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerBankId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerBankId")]
    public virtual CustomerBank CustomerBank { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerLink> CustomerLink { get; set; }
}
```

My view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerAddressId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerAddressBillingId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerBankId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Address", "EditAddress", new { id = Model.CustomerId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Billing Address", "EditAddressBilling", new { id = Model.CustomerId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Bank Details", "EditBank", new { id = Model.CustomerId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Links", "EditLink", new { id = Model.CustomerId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

And my controller method :

```
 // GET: /Customer/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Customer customer = _db.GetCustomer(id);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(customer);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Edit(customer);
            _db.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

What's really weird is that the CustomerId value is not null in the controller, but i do exactly the same thing with CustomerAddressId, and this one is null.
Any suggestion?

Comment: What does the HttpGet action do?  Please show how you are loading the model for display.

Comment: I've edited my post with the get method

Comment: Just a thought - your CustomerAddressId  and other fields are nullable.  They're not null because they should be null in this instance?

Comment: They can be null at a moment, but once the address is created and associated, they are no more null. When i go on the edit page, the field CustomerAddressId have the good value (i tried with a textbox instead of hidden, just to check). But when i click "Save" and then arrive in the Post method, the CustomerAddressId== null, even if in the view it has a value...  :/

Comment: Can it be because it's a foreign key or something?

Comment: At the point where the Customer is loaded from the database your HttpGet Edit action, are the values all correct?

Comment: Yep, when the get method pass the customer to the view, the values are good, and in the view also, the values are correct. But when i post the form, in the post method, the customer that i have misses some values

Comment: Is that directly on entry to the post method, or does something funky happen inside _db.Edit(customer) ?

Comment: No, directly, i have a breakpoint on  if (ModelState.IsValid), and i inspect the customer in the method parameters

Comment: Can't explain why that's happening (I suspect it's an EF thing) but do you really need to have those fields (CustomerAddressId, CustomerBillingAddressId etc) in your view at all? Looks like they aren't being used?

Comment: I don't need them in the view but i need them in the controller, to update my customer properly. If i don't have those values, then the customer is updated with "null" for those values, which results in an unassignment for adress, adressbilling and bank  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found out, my properties was not properly binded in my model ^^